# unable to return result using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery UI's slider and i want to return the results from multiple sliders so I can performs a calculation.

this is what i have so far but I'm struggling to get any results from out side the function.

```
$(function() {
  var x
  $("#slider4").slider({
      value: 1,
      min: 0,
      max: 50,
      step: 5,
      slide: function(event, ui) {
          $("#items").val("$" + ui.value);
          x =$("#items").val("$" + ui.value);
      }

  });
  $("#items").val("$" + $("#slider4").slider("value"));
  console.log(x) // this doesnt update the console with the slider value
 });
```

Ideally outside the function i would want to add multiple slider results similar to below.

```
var z = x * y;
```

Comment: It looks like `$("#slider4").slider("value")` should return `1`. Are you saying that's not the case?

Comment: Your code works: http://jsfiddle.net/yza37cah/. Aside from the unnecessary string concatenation on when setting `val()`, do you have a problem with it?

Comment: yes it does but what i need is when the slider changes, the value of x to be available external of the function

Comment: You mean like setting `window.x` if you want to use some sort of global-like variable?

Comment: @rob — Well… it is available globally already (it really isn't clear what the problem is here), but you'd probably be better off just using `$("#slider4").slider("value")` directly when you needed the value.

Comment: when I do console.log(x) this doesnt update the console with the slider value. the #items is updating.

Comment: Why would `console.log(x) // this doesnt update the console with the slider value` update the console when you change the value? You're running it when you load the page, not when you update the value.

Comment: here is the https://jsfiddle.net/pp749snc/ to give you an idea i want to add all the values together to produce a result

Answer (score 1):

To get the value of the slider outside of the `slide` handler you can either retrieve the value of `#items` (as you update that within the `slide` handler):

```
var sliderValue = $('#items').val();
```

Or you can read the value from the `slider()` directly:

```
var sliderValue = $('#slier4').slider('option', 'value');
```

Also, note that you do not need to append empty strings when setting `val()`:

```
$("#slider4").slider({
    value: 1,
    min: 0,
    max: 50,
    step: 5,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        $("#items").val(ui.value);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Rory, I've updated my code to hopefully give you more of an idea of what i am trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

The value does not magically keep updating the textbox, you need to write code that updates the value when the slider value changes. So add a [change event](https://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-change)

```
change: function( event, ui ) { $("#items").val(ui.value); }
```

Comment: the text box works fine, my issue is storing the result after it has changed and then doing a calculation. i plan to have multiple sliders and based on the selection complete a calculation and present the total to the user

Comment: So read the values of the sliders when you run the calculation! I am not sure what your issue is exactly...